# Spark Dataset - map option[T] fields

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I wonder how to work on datasets columns that are nullable (Option[T]).
My goal is to use the spark dataset API (such "Map") and benefit from the compilation time typed advantages. (I do not want to use the dataframe API such "select")

Take this example: I d'like to apply functions on columns. This only works fine when the column is not nullable.

```
val schema = List(
    StructField("name", StringType, false)
  , StructField("age", IntegerType, true)
  , StructField("children", IntegerType, false)
)

val data = Seq(
  Row("miguel", null, 0),
  Row("luisa", 21, 1)
)

val df = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),
  StructType(schema)
)

case class Person(name: String, age: Option[Int], children: Int)
//                                    ^
//                                    |
//                                 age is nullable
df.as[Person].map(x => x.children * 12).show
//+-----+
//|value|
//+-----+
//|    0|
//|   12|
//+-----+
df.as[Person].map(x => x.age * 12).show
//<console>:36: error: value * is not a member of Option[Int]
//       df.as[Person].map(x => x.age * 12).show
```

Can anybody point me on a easy way to multiply this nullable age column by 12 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is an `Option` you can transform it directly. Instead `map`:

```
df.as[Person].map(x => x.age.map(_ * 12)).show

// +-----+
// |value|
// +-----+
// | null|
// |  252|
// +-----+
```

In practice I'd just `select`:

```
df.select(($"age" * 12).as[Int]).show
// +----------+
// |(age * 12)|
// +----------+
// |      null|
// |       252|
// +----------+
```

It will perform better and when you call `as[Person]` you already loose most of the static type checking benefits.

Comment: could you clarify a bit why "as[Person]  loose most of the static type checking benefits." I had in mind the opposite.Thanks

Comment: `as[Person]` is telling compiler what is the type. It has no way to check if `DataFrame` can be converted to the declared class or not. Starting with `spark.read.text` or similar and parsing manually would give better guarantees.

Comment: Would you say that `as[Person]` is always waste of time, and casting columns is a better way of getting typed `dataframe` aka `datasets` ?